# Selecting a circular region in 2D scatter plot

Tags: plotting

I have a 2D scatter plot. Now I want to select a circular region in this plot and use the data inside the circular region for further analysis.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `Select` and `Norm`:

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {1000, 2}];
center = {5, 3};
radius = 2;
good = Select[pts, Norm[# - center] < radius &];

Show[ListPlot[{pts, good}], Graphics@Circle[center, radius],  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Your last line could be a bit simpler `ListPlot[{pts, good}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Epilog -> Circle[center, radius]]` ;-)

Comment: That's right :) Could you explain why `AspectRatio -> Automatic` is not the same as default?

Comment: This should give you a hint: `GoldenRatio AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[ListPlot[{}]]`

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I don't know why I expect `Automatic` settings to be default. A bit like in `NDSolve`, `Method -> Automatic` does not change anything (afaik).

Answer (score 8):

I'd use Nearest instead of Select, as it is much faster. Compare

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {10^5, 2}];
center = {5, 3};
radius = 2;

sub1 = Select[pts, Norm[# - center] < radius &]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.538735`, Null}

```
sub2 = Nearest[pts, center, {All, radius}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.002293`, Null}

```
ListPlot[{pts, #}, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> Automatic] & /@ {sub1, sub2}
```

[image]

The points sets might differ due to different boundary inclusion interpretation by Nearest and Select. But those could be easily adjusted by the radius value.